# learning django and i getting this, TemplateSyntaxError, message

Tags: django

[erro message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtVlL.png)

```
16          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
17          <ul class="menu">
18              <li {% if section=="dashboard" %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
19                  <a href="{% url 'dashboard'%}">My dashboard</a>
20              </li>
21         
28          {% endif %}
```

this is the code thats giving me the error i don't know what am i doing wrong

error message: Could not parse the remainder: '=="dashboard"' from 'section=="dashboard"'

Answer (score 4):

Francisco,

You need to put a space between the operator (`==`) and the variable (`section`) and the value to be compared (`"dashboard"`).

```
          {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="menu">
              <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>
                  <a href="{% url 'dashboard'%}">My dashboard</a>
              </li>
         
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: its not working even if i place the space inbetween

Comment: look at the error message image... and visual studio code is making one of the equals(=) red. I don't know why

Comment: In the image you posted i see that you didn't fix the code. Please insert a space around the equals (`==`) operator in the `{% if %}` tags used in the list items (`<li>`) and try again.

Comment: ok i did add the space and its working now. I had to use a regular text editor, because visual studio code was automatically removing the space in betweeen